# Using phpHaml or PhamlP - Very Confused On How To Do So

Tags: php, haml, codekit

I am trying to write my first wordpress theme, and I am using `haml` but I stumbled into a problem when I want to write statements such as the following, but in `haml`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/reset.css" type="text/css">
```

I thought the `haml` equivalent would simply use a `:plain` tag for the `php` but then I realised this would quickly turn very ugly, and it didn't much work.

So I am stuck with this:

```
%link{ :rel => "stylesheet", :href => "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>" }
```

Which, of course, is wrong.

I have had a look at `phpHaml` and `PhamlP` but I have no idea how to use them for my need of using a `php` statement inside a `:href` attribute in haml.

I am using CodeKit to recompile `haml` into `php` by simply changing the extension it compiles to from `.html` to `.php` and a lot of the documentation, to my understanding, requires I import their files in another `.php` file to use their parsers.

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do?

**Basically using php inline with haml, as easily as possible.**

Answer (score 1):

There is a way - the kind folks at WeLaika have created a plugin for wordpress called [Wordless](http://welaika.github.io/wordless/)

It does exactly what you are asking (to use php inline with haml) as it is bundled with the phaml parser.

It requires a working ruby environment (using rvm) on your machine, and then you can write using ruby style "layouts and views" templates. It also allows for the use of [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) in your stylesheets and [Coffescript](http://coffeescript.org/) for your Javascript. But these are, of course, optional.

I also recommend using the two gems, [Wordmove](https://github.com/welaika/wordmove) and [Wordless_Gem](https://github.com/etienne/wordless_gem)

Answer (score 0):

In Phamlp I use this:

```
%link(rel="stylesheet" href="#{ bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') }")
```

Comment: I know it's a bit too late, but if someone have the same problem it helps.